# scrapy log issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, scrapyd

i have multiple spiders in one project , problem is right now i am defining **LOG_FILE** in SETTINGS like

```
LOG_FILE = "scrapy_%s.log" % datetime.now()
```

what i want is `scrapy_SPIDERNAME_DATETIME`

but i am unable to provide spidername in log_file name ..

i found

```
scrapy.log.start(logfile=None, loglevel=None, logstdout=None)
```

and called it in each spider **init** method but its not working ..

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why isn't it working? Provide some error messages and what you are expecting.

Comment: @Qiau thanks for pointing out i just accepted all correct answers , 
there is no error so far ,but scrapy.log.start(logfile='output.log', loglevel=log.DEBUG, logstdout=None) is not creating any log file...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spider's `__init__()` is not early enough to call `log.start()` by itself since the log observer is already started at this point; therefore, you need to reinitialize the logging state to trick Scrapy into (re)starting it.

In your spider class file:

```
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/"]

    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        LOG_FILE = "scrapy_%s_%s.log" % (self.name, datetime.now())
        # remove the current log
        # log.log.removeObserver(log.log.theLogPublisher.observers[0])
        # re-create the default Twisted observer which Scrapy checks
        log.log.defaultObserver = log.log.DefaultObserver()
        # start the default observer so it can be stopped
        log.log.defaultObserver.start()
        # trick Scrapy into thinking logging has not started
        log.started = False
        # start the new log file observer
        log.start(LOG_FILE)
        # continue with the normal spider init
        super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
```

And the output file might look like:

`scrapy_example_2012-08-25 12:34:48.823896.log`

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work for me. Kept getting "ERROR" in scrapy shell, that's it. Couldn't debug properly. Anyway, this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16092502/2689986 did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There should be [a BOT_NAME](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=bot_name#bot-name) in your settings.py. This is the project/spider name. So in your case, this would be

```
LOG_FILE = "scrapy_%s_%s.log" % (BOT_NAME, datetime.now())
```

This is pretty much the same that Scrapy does [internally](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/log.py#L94)

But why not use [log.msg](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html?highlight=log#scrapy.log.msg). The docs clearly state that this is for spider specific stuff. It might be easier to use this and just extract/grep/... the different spider log messages from a big log file.

A more compicated approach would be to get the location of the spider [SPIDER_MODULES](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=bot_name#spider-modules) list and load all spiders inside these package.

Comment: BOT_NAME in setting.py has entire project name not spider name , lets see i have one project call "mall" that have a_mall , b_mall, c_mall spiders i need that names

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scrapy's **[Storage URI parameters](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#storage-uri-parameters)** in your settings.py file for **FEED URI**.

1. %(name)s
2. %(time)s

   For example: /tmp/crawled/%(name)s/%(time)s.log

Comment: Just extra info. I know you don't need it :)