# Logging to specific error log file in scrapy

Tags: python, logging, web-scraping, scrapy

I am running a log of scrapy by doing this:

```
from scrapy import log
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "myspider"  

  def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        LOG_FILE = "logs/spider.log"
        log.log.defaultObserver = log.log.DefaultObserver()
        log.log.defaultObserver.start()
        log.started = False
        log.start(LOG_FILE, loglevel=log.INFO)
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)

    def parse(self,response):
        ....
        raise Exception("Something went wrong!")
        log.msg('Something went wrong!', log.ERROR)

        # Somehow write to a separate error log here.
```

Then I run the spider like this:

```
scrapy crawl myspider
```

This would store all the log.INFO data as well as log.ERROR into `spider.log`.

If an error occurs, I would also like to store those details in a separate log file called `spider_errors.log`. It would make it easier to search for errors that occurred rather than trying to scan through the entire `spider.log` file (which could be huge).

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT:**

Trying with PythonLoggingObserver:

```
def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        LOG_FILE = 'logs/spider.log'
        ERR_File = 'logs/spider_error.log'

        observer = log.log.PythonLoggingObserver()
        observer.start()

        log.started = False     
        log.start(LOG_FILE, loglevel=log.INFO)
        log.start(ERR_FILE, loglevel=log.ERROR)
```

But I get `ERROR: No handlers could be found for logger "twisted"`

Comment: Where is `MySpider` defined?

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth Sorry, the code was just a snippet. I've updated it to be more complete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just let [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) do the job. Try to use `PythonLoggingObserver` instead of `DefaultObserver`:

- configure two loggers (one for `INFO` and one for `ERROR` messages) directly in python, or via fileconfig, or via dictconfig (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html))
- start it in spider's `__init__`:

  ```
  def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
      # TODO: configure logging: e.g. logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
      observer = log.PythonLoggingObserver()
      observer.start()
  ```

Let me know if you need help with configuring loggers.

EDIT:

Another option is to start two file log observers in `__init__.py`:

```
from scrapy.log import ScrapyFileLogObserver
from scrapy import log


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "myspider"  

    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider.log", 'w'), level=logging.INFO).start()
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider_error.log", 'w'), level=logging.ERROR).start()

        super(MySpider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)

    ...
```

Comment: I keep getting the error `ERROR: No handlers could be found for logger "twisted"`.

Comment: The twisted error went away using your suggested ScrapyFileLogObserver, but now it doesn't log anything that comes from `log.msg('SOME ERROR MESG', log.ERROR)`. Is there a way to specify `logstdout=True` with SCrapyFileLogObserver?

Comment: Hm, that didn't work either. I do see the Exception message though, so I guess that's fine for now. I'll accept the answer since logging to an error file does work. I'd still be willing to try out other suggestions about the `log.err()` problem, if you'd like to continue. Thanks again!